# Alternative to Youtube app on iPad

Tags: youtube, ipad-app

I'd like to know what alternatives are out there for the Youtube app on the iPad. Particularly I'm interested in an advanced search option to be able to search videos by duration, not watched, and without restricted content. Also it would be pretty cool if the app opens directly links to youtube videos showing the video right away in full screen, no comments, annotation suggestions or whatever, just the video.

**Update**

I had to remove the Youtube app to give some priority to look for an alternative, the app was pretty much useless at that point, it removed my watched history without any warning in a cannel with hundreds of videos that I want to watch in an ordered way, also I always stumble with videos with restricted content, that are either muted or not played at all, I don't know why they continue showing me those results if I can't play those videos.

Also most of the time I'm not interested in the comments nor suggestions, I'd like to have a way to watch the video right a way in full screen, specially when the app doesn't respond too well to my touches or gestures, the button to exit fullscreen is tiny, and I almost always have to tap on it more than once because it's near the border of the screen; the minimize gesture to move the video page to a picture in picture frame near the right corner has to be a perfect diagonal on the screen or it will be executed poorly or not at all.

Comment: From within the youtube website, you can search for video duration, among other parameters.

Comment: Tubex allows filtering for duration. Not even the official website allows for filtering by not watched and without restricted content; does that matter that much for you?

Comment: @user165604 I'll give Tubex a try, thanks for the suggestion. Regarding the not watched and w/o restricted content I guess I'll have to wait until it's available in the oficial.